# Ship Controls modeling Real life Physics

Tags: xna, c#

I am working on a 2D ship that will fly around in space (for now, no friction or gravity). The controls are similar to the game Asteroids. My problem is that I am having trouble connecting some variables to real life applications.

For example, if I'm defining the ships velocity, which in real physics is V=distance traveled (or change in position)/time. Should velocity be a Vector2 or just a float (or int). It's how far an object moves so I would think it to be just a single integer or number but then again, your moving on an X and Y axis so shouldn't there be two velocities? One for the X and another for the Y? The velocity being a vector2 actually works really well but when I'm doing other formulas, which are floats or ints, that require velocity I run into issues because I don't have a single number then.

Another issue i'm having trouble grasping is the direction. My code for the direction is:

```
shipVariables.shipDirection = new Vector2((float)Math.Sin(shipVariables.shipRotation), -(float)Math.Cos(shipVariables.shipRotation));
```

Which works but it will immediately turns the ship if you rotate the object while moving "forward". My most successful approach to this method was doing this:

```
shipVariables.shipDirection += new Vector2((float)Math.Sin(shipVariables.shipRotation), -(float)Math.Cos(shipVariables.shipRotation));
```

The effect I like is that instead of just turning, it essentially has to overcome the previous direction to move to the next. The part I don't like is that it gains speed way to much and it's supposed to just be a direction, not a direction and magnitude.

If I have the velocity and I can get the direction, I will be able to calculate everything else with other formulas that I know (momentum, acceleration, etc...).

Any tips to lead me in the right directions would be great, thanks.

Comment: Have you taken any of Vector Algebra, Calculus, or Mechanics (Physics) at a first year university level? I believe you will need at least these three subjects in order to build your game.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I am currently in Physics and Calculus. I understand physics and Vector Algebra very well, I just can't seem to grasp putting physics in a 2D dimension. We have never (yet) used Physics in a 2D level either yet, this game is just for fun.

Comment: My guess is you are still a term or two away from really being able to tackle this material with confidence. Here are two thoughts for consideration: 1) Work on non-technical aspects of your game for a bit, until your studies catch up; or 2) with the Christmas break upon us, devote 1 week of it to advancing your knowledge in Vector Algebra. That is, get a Vector Algebra text and do 1 weeks' worth of material each day for 5 or 6 days. That half-term of material should be enough to really advance your ability to work on the game; and will help your grades also. Bonus!

Comment: If you have access to a copy of Feynman Lectures on Physics, Volume 1, you could do worse than to browse a few chapters of that.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Alright, thanks for all the input. I plan on looking over most of that over break (I do have access to Feynman Lectures on Physics, Volume 1).

Comment: Chapters 11 and 18 might be useful. (I don't really have themmemorized - I just looked them up.)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Yes, I saw that too, thanks. It's actually really helpful as next I was going to have to do some research on collisions which will really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Physics for simple points in 2D is basically the same as doing 1D physics twice - once for each dimension (X and Y). So you can use the same formulas you would use on `float`s on `Vector2`s and it generally "just works".

But if you add rotation, you must calculate a 1D angular "dimension" as well. (It's more of a "[degree of freedom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(mechanics))".)

So start with your variables:

```
float angle;
// You could have a "float angularVelocity" here if you wanted
Vector2 position;
Vector2 velocity;
```

And then update something like this:

```
if(leftKey)
    angle -= rotateAmount;
if(rightKey)
    angle += rotateAmount;

// Note: A proper cartesian coordinate system with "Y+ = up" would be (cos, sin).
//       But I'll just use what you have:
Vector2 direction = new Vector2((float)Math.Sin(angle), -(float)Math.Cos(angle));

float thrust = thrustKey ? 1f : 0f;

velocity += direction * thrust * time;
position += velocity * time;
```

Finally: Generally don't use `int` for physics. It is for integer (whole) values, which makes it difficult to get the desired results. A `Vector2` is made up of two `float`s.